# How to make a Widget come from below and stack itself on top of current screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Duolingo's app, there is an element that comes animated from the bottom and displays some text every time you answer a question (see image below).

How to replicate that feature with Flutter?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the bottom sheet that's coming up?

Comment: Yes, that red element that comes up on top of the rest of the current screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) widget. Here is a simple usage of this widget:

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext bc){
      return Container(
        child: new Wrap(
        children: <Widget>[
         new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.music_note),
           title: new Text('Music'),
          onTap: () => {}          
         ),
         new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.videocam),
          title: new Text('Video'),
          onTap: () => {},          
         ),
        ],
      ),
      );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read an article about how to use Bottom sheets [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433)

I hope this will help you.